# Is a zucchini that had a maggot under the flower still safe to eat?

Tags: pests, zucchini

My zucchini plant had vine borer. I did surgery on the plant to get rid of it and covered it back with soil.

Before I did all of that, I  cut off a zucchini that was ready to be picked. I took off the dried up end blossom and there was little white like maggot where the blossom was. The vegetable look perfectly fine. It wasn't over-ripened.

Is it still safe to eat?

Answer (score 3):

Meh, it's protein. The grub's made of the same stuff you're eating. And the rest of the vegetable is in pristine condition.

You can cut out the section that's had grub activity (if it's been eaten into) and the rest is just fine to eat. Same goes for an ear of corn that had a corn ear worm take out kernels or an apple that's had an apple borer in it. Cut out what's been gnawed and eat the rest.

Where you worry is when rot has set in and you have fly maggots, then it truly is compost heap material.